# How to trigger an angular js watch in a specific browser window, when close another browser window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I need to trigger an angular js `watch` in a specific browser window, when I close another browser window. I used `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` for save the message and then use a watch for them, but didn't worked. Any suggestion?

Example:

```
//First controller in browser window 1. Listen for the event:

  $scope.$watch(function () {
            return localStorage.composeTransferDatas;
        }, function (newVal, oldVal) {           
            if(newVal != oldVal){
                console.log('Hi');             
            }
        }, true);


//Second controller in browser window 2. Save data in localStorage:

  var arrayWindows = JSON.parse(localStorage.composeTransferDatas);
  arrayWindows['test'] = {data : data, type: type};
  localStorage.composeTransferDatas = JSON.stringify(arrayWindows);
  $window.close();
```

Expected that the watch in the first controller was triggered, but it didn't. However the localStorage is actually changed.

Comment: Do you have any code you could show?

Comment: I already update the question. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I dont think watch can see your localStorage, because it is only binded to &scope. Let me see if I can find a way to bind it to localStorage

Comment: try $localStorage instead of just localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ngStoage Module and use the same code with $localStorage

```
  $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $localStorage.composeTransferDatas;
        }, function (newVal, oldVal) {           
            if(newVal != oldVal){
                console.log('Hi');             
            }
        }, true);
```